# How to get an email adress from downloaded html file?

Tags: html, web-scraping, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape web pages of psychotherapists profiles via R.

My goal is to get the email of the therapist which is displayed as a link.
An example of the page: http://academyofct.site-ym.com/members/?id=44410428

The browser displays this piece of code as:

```
<a href="mailto:abonfil@cogbtherapy.com">abonfil@cogbtherapy.com</a>
```

But when I download the page (via Ctrl+S) for parsing and getting the email adress this part of code disappears from the html file.

Could anyone explain me, what's a problem? And how can I get a full web page for extract email?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That element is being added to the DOM from client-side JavaScript; see this part of the source:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
    var strEmail = CharShiftDecrypt('ghutlor@iumhznkxgvE.ius', 6, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789');
    document.write('<a href="mailto:'+ strEmail + '">'+ strEmail + '</a><br>');
//--></script>
```

The only way you can get that content is by first executing the JavaScript the way browsers do. So unless you’re using a processor which executes that JavaScript, you won’t be able to scrape it.

What you’d need to do is to either use Selenium and/or WebDriver, or use something based on PhantomJS or similar. Those all cause a headless browser engine to be run, which executes the JavaScript and gives you the same DOM you’d get from navigating to the site yourself in a browser.

Here are some how-to guides on a few available options:

- [How to Scrape Javascript Rendered Websites with Python & Selenium](https://medium.com/@hoppy/how-to-test-or-scrape-javascript-rendered-websites-with-python-selenium-a-beginner-step-by-c137892216aa)
- [Scraping a Ghost blog with PhantomJS and SlimerJS using CasperJS](https://badacadabra.github.io/Scraping-a-Ghost-blog-with-PhantomJS-and-SlimerJS-using-CasperJS/)
- [Scraping a JS-Rendered Page](https://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php)
- [Ultimate guide for scraping  JavaScript rendered web pages](https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/)
- [dryscrape—“A lightweight Python library that uses Webkit to enable easy scraping of dynamic, Javascript-heavy web pages“](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape)
- [pjscrape—“A web-scraping framework written in Javascript, using PhantomJS and jQuery”](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/pjscrape)

Comment: So, as I understand I need to simulate browser work or embedded some JavaScript require to my script for scraping. Right?

Comment: Right. For some how-to guides on a few of the available options, see the updates just now added to the end of the answer